# C++ Getting Data from file to remember last session

Tags: c++, file, struct

What I'm looking to do is have the items, timestamp, and completed status saved to a file, which it does, and then when the program is restarted, the data will be restored to the list from the file. Right now, I can get the info to save to the file "data.txt" but it will not read it in, and that's what I'm looking to ultimately accomplish.

```
                    // Get previous session data
                    fin.open("c:/temp/data.txt", ios::in);

                    if (fin.fail())
                    {
                        cout << "Failed to open file for reading" << endl;
                        return 0;
                    }

                    for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
                    {
                        fin >> list[i].completed;
                        fin >> list[i].timestamp;
                        getline(fin, list[i].items);
                    }
                    fin.close();
```

Comment: What's happening exactly when you read ?

Comment: Please tell us what exactly is going wrong, so we can help you fixing your problem? How are you trying to load the data? Why doesn't it work (exceptions, wrong results)? Besides that, I would recommend using a serialization library to accomplish things like that. Personally I use [cereal](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/), which I think is amazing, but there is also a serialization module in the boost library.

Comment: With a little thought you could remove at least 90% of this code and still reproduce the problem. Don't ask people here to wade through irrelevant stuff.

Comment: So the user enters data into the program, which will store it into the corresponding struct members. That data is then outputted into the data.txt file. When the program is reloaded, I would like for it to grab that information from the file, and in a sense "restore" the session from where it left off, and use that info from the file. Right now, it will store the data to the file, but when I say go to sort or remove an item after I have restarted the program, it wipes the data.txt file.

Comment: @bradym55 Then please show us only the code responsible for reloading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's wrong ?

There are plenty of issues in your code.  But let's start with the beginning.

When `main()` starts, `numItem` is intialized to 0.

When you later add an item, you open the file.  At this moment, `numItem` is sitll 0. You then read the file by doing:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)  //<=== ouch !!! numItem is still 0 
      ...
```

SO you loop on a counter which is 0.  So nothing gets read from the file.

The list then contains only the manually added items, if you added some. Or the list is still empty.

WHat ever you do afterwards, you work with an empty or almost empty list.

When you exit, you overwrite the file with an empty list, so it gets scrapped !!

### How to solve it ?

One possible solution could be to write right at the start of the file the number of items.  When reading the file, the first thing you would then do is read this into `numItem`.  Then you could use the kind of look construct that you have.

Another alternative would be to read the file using a while loop, and incrementing numItem while you read the file.  Up to you to choose the most suitable solution.

### Other issues

You are reading the file, everytime the user wants to add some elements.  This is a problem because the file is reread each time, potentially overwritting data...

according to your explanations, you should read your persistent data only one:  in main() and before you enter the menu loop.

Now in the meantime you've removed most of your code.  But I think there could be also a potential problem in memory allocation (I suppose it's some homework and you're not yet allowed to use standard library containers such as vectors).  Check that you've allocated some memory for reading your data into list **before** populating the array.